# Ruby: Bundler's Mustermann `initialize` wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, sinatra

I am following the steps of a GitHub tutorial on [setting up a dev environment to create a GitHub app](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/setting-up-your-development-environment-to-create-a-github-app). Unfortunately, I'm stuck on Step 6 of the tutorial, as when I enter `bundle exec ruby template_server.rb` I receive this error:

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:29: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:29: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:35: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:35: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:44: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann/regular.rb:22:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann/pattern.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann/pattern.rb:59:in `block in new'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann/equality_map.rb:43:in `fetch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann/pattern.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann.rb:67:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann.rb:70:in `block in new'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann.rb:70:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann.rb:70:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1641:in `compile'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1629:in `compile!'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1271:in `error'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1838:in `<class:Base>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:894:in `<module:Sinatra>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/main.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/main.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.4/lib/sinatra.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from template_server.rb:1:in `require'
        from template_server.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I haven't changed either the [Gemfile](https://github.com/github-developer/creating-ci-tests-with-the-checks-api/blob/master/Gemfile) or the [Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/github-developer/creating-ci-tests-with-the-checks-api/blob/master/Gemfile.lock) (they're the same as the ones in the tutorial so I provided their hyperlinks) and from what I've read so far there must be something outdated, but I'm not sure what exactly. Thanks!

Comment: You have run into the kwargs transition that occurred in [ruby 3](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/). To run that template as is you will need to use ruby <3.0 or you will need to update the Gemfile dependencies (specifically `sinatra`) and hope it still works.

Comment: Yeah I tried updating both mustermann and bundle, both to no avail. Will try again later with ruby <3.0. Unfortunate that there doesn't seem to be a solution for "modern" Ruby versions